# Retrieve data from two table from parse using swift

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I have two tables in my parse database. The first table is the users table, that contains users info like username, email, password,profile pic etc.
The second table contains posts added by users. I want to fetch a post along with the details of the user who added that post. Can any one suggest me how to do that in swift language.

I have tried the following code :

```
let innerQuery = PFQuery(className: "Posts")
    innerQuery.whereKey("pickUpLocation", equalTo: firstSectionLbls[0] as! String)
    innerQuery.whereKey("destination", equalTo: firstSectionLbls[1] as! String)
    innerQuery.limit = 10
    innerQuery.skip = skip
    innerQuery.orderByAscending("DepartureDate")

    let query = PFUser.query()
    query!.whereKey("username", matchesQuery: innerQuery)

    query!.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (results: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
```

I have retried using pointer. These are the steps I used to create pointer.
1. created a column named user in users table and set its type to pointer. 
2. Created another column with same name as "user" in another class named "Posts" as set its type to pointer.

Then I used the below code to fetch the user data along with post data.

```
   let innerQuery = PFQuery(className: "Rides")
    innerQuery.whereKey("pickUpLocation", equalTo: firstSectionLbls[0] as! String)
    innerQuery.whereKey("destination", equalTo: firstSectionLbls[1] as! String)
    innerQuery.limit = 10
    innerQuery.skip = skip
    innerQuery.includeKey("user")
    innerQuery.orderByAscending("DepartureDate")

    innerQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (results: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
```

But now again I didnot receive the users data, though I received the posts data

Comment: So what have you tried? StackOverflow isn't a code writing service

Comment: why you people always under estimate others. You think I haven't tried. I have tried the above code.

Comment: Does the posts class include a pointer to the posting user?  If so then just use `includeKey` for the user pointer column in your posts query.

Comment: I haven't used a pointer. But I am trying right now.

Comment: Hello, I have tried using pointer. But may be I am not aware how to use a pointer. Can you please let me know the right way?

Comment: Have you read the documentation? https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide#relations

Comment: Yes, I did but somehow I coudn't come up with a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To relate posts to a user, create a column in your Post table, calling it user (or author or whatever). Use a Pointer column. Then, when you create a post, associate it with the current user, i.e. like this:

```
newPost["user"] = PFUser.currentUser()
```

Then, when you save it, Parse will store a pointer to the current user's user record in the user column.

Now, when you do your query, you can get the user object together with the post object by using `includeKey` the way you did.